# Prevent fake gateway device attached to PC's network card

Tags: network, linux, network-access-control

Office. Several PCs with Linux. Internet is limited on gateway level, so nobody could do POST-requests over HTTP.

We prepared several measures to prevent data leakage on infrastructure level, but wondering:

Is it possible to prevent attacks like attaching a hardware network device to the PC's straight by wire to immitate a fake gateway? That way user can avoid all office-wide network restrictions and copy something right on this device.

Storage devices (USB and such) are already disabled.

End goal: prevent data leak by some of our employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to prevent attacks like attaching a hardware network device to the PC's straight by wire to immitate a fake gateway? That way user can avoid all office-wide network restrictions and copy something right on this device.

I assume in my answer that the user has no root access to the system, cannot boot any other system or simply remove the hard disk and access it directly, because otherwise (s)he could just circumvent the existing protections.

Since a knowledgeable user might simulate a full router including the MAC address of the original router (s)he could add a fake router. In this case your only option would be to make sure that the system connects only to properly identified routers, i.e. use a VPN to the router or similar. Same is true with the user attaching some network attached storage etc, that is you must make sure that the computer can only communicate with a limited number of fully identified systems.

> ... so nobody could do POST-requests over HTTP. ... End goal: prevent data leak by some of our employees.

It is possible to transfer data within the URL or within the HTTP headers of a GET request, so restricting POST is not enough as long as the user can communicate with a web sites under his own control. 
Apart from that the user might just take photos of the information, write it down or simply remember the information and write it down at home. If you don't trust users that much you they should probably don't get access to the information.

Restricting POST requests only protects against accidental leaks of information or against non-technical users. But these users will probably not try to add an alternative router in order to leak data.

If you care about transfer of huge amounts of information which cannot be simply remembered or photographed then it might be the best that these data are not available from the internet environment by having dedicated systems (hardware or VM) to access the internet and these systems should not have access to the relevant data.

Comment: Good point. You're right, there are plenty of things to reconsider. Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, turn off the pc or hibernate it. As long as there is no data leaving the pc through that interface you have nothing to worry about. I linux you can simply use iptables to block all traffic leaving the computer, just to be sure.

Stay safe ;)

Comment: Looks like my post not explaining it correctly, updated it with more context. Basically we giving our users restricted internet access in business hours, and wondering how we can prevent users faking gateway by attaching some hardware device straight to the PC at that time. Thanks for response anyway!